# Top Level Exception - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been getting Top level exception in android studio, i am using appcompat and sliding menu library. I know i am getting the exception because of conflict of Android Support Libraries as explained in some of the previous threads in stackoverflow. I have tried All the the methods shown in threads like including configuraion etc.

**here is my Build.gradle(root)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    configurations {
        // to avoid double inclusion of support libraries
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Here is my Build.Gradle(App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.danaraddi.cprograms"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 9
        versionName "7.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
}

// animations
dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.0.8@aar'
}

// inject views
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
}

dependencies {
    // Your other dependencies go here
    compile project(':library')
}
```

Here is my Build.Gradle(Lib - SlidingMenu)

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

}
```

**Here is my Log Cat**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Callback;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

**PS : I Have places configuration in root,app build.gradle too , it builds successfully after a clean project and then after the same error.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

instead of

```
dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
```

to `build.gradle` file inside the android block

Comment: should i remove  configurations {
        // to avoid double inclusion of support libraries
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

Comment: I removed that and it is working fine :) Thanks a lot

Comment: yup, remove or comment it

Comment: After I added the line. I have problem: "Class com.... has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies."